# My project should read a json file but generate a error

Tags: c++, json

i have made a example for try the JsonCpp library.

I have included it in my project, the project content is this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <json\value.h>
#include <json\json.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Json::Reader reader;  //for reading the data
    Json::Value newValue; //for modifying and storing new values
    Json::StyledStreamWriter writer; //for writing in json files

    //opening file using fstream
    ifstream file("items.json");

    // check if there is any error is getting data from the json file
    if (!reader.parse(file, newValue)) {
        cout << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << newValue["Category"] << endl;

    file.close();

    system("pause");

}
```

The json file name is items.json and its content is this:

```
{
    "Category" : "Technical",
    "Date" : "1 January 2021",
    "Name" : "Java2Blog",
    "first" : "Shishank",
    "last" : "Jain"
}
```

But when i compile and run the project, it generate this error:

```
* Line 1, Column 1
  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.
```

I have followed this guide: https://java2blog.com/json-parser-cpp/

this is my first time using json in a C ++ project

Comment: `json\value.h` should be `json/value.h` and `json\json.h` should be `json/json.h`

Comment: Is your `json` file UTF8 encoded? The program works for me if I change the above `include`s and put your `items.json` content in an UTF8 encoded file.

Comment: Use a string-stream to hardcode the file content into the [mcve]. If that works, check the encoding. It should be UTF-8 without BOM (effectively ASCII for this specific content). If you have a BOM or different encoding (UTF-16, for example), this will fail.

Comment: I checked the site you are learning from. It doesn't look like it's written by someone very familiar with C++. I'd try to find a better learning resource (and no, I don't have any to recommend).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I have tried but nothing changes

Comment: Then try @UlrichEckhardt's suggestion. Put the file's content in an `istringstream`, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jjMEGoazo)

Comment: For All, I have controlled the file encoding and it is UTF-8

Comment: @Titan be sure there's no BOM though.

Comment: If you run [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjre6M5KT) program, what does it print? Does it print any of the [BOM](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) sequences, like `ef bb bf`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i tried it end it generated nothing

Comment: In that case, it failed to open the file. Make sure the file is in your current directory when you run the program.

Comment: @Titan I'd recommend you check that using Notepad++ which is exact as possible at file encoding detection. Especially on Windows systems, writing a BOM with selected encoding methods is often an unwanted default behavior, and widely classes with standard encoding behavior at other systems.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved my problem.

The json file was already encoded in UTF-8, and the file path was correct.

I have changed my code like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <json\json.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
    ifstream file;
    file.open("items.json");

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "File non esiste" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Json::Reader reader;  //for reading the data
        Json::Value value; //for modifying and storing new values
        reader.parse(file, value);
        cout << value["Category"] << endl;
    }

    file.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

I apologize to everyone for the inconvenience

Comment: This code assumes that reader.parse always succeeds when file exists. Do not use it in real program.